# Creating reference to HDF dataset in H5py using astype

Tags: python, numpy, h5py, hdf

From the [h5py docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#Dataset.astype), I see that I can cast a HDF dataset as another type using `astype` method for the datasets. This returns a contextmanager which performs the conversion on-the-fly.

However, I would like to read in a dataset stored as `uint16` and then cast it into `float32` type. Thereafter, I would like to extract various slices from this dataset in a different function as the cast type `float32`. The docs explains the use as

```
with dataset.astype('float32'):
   castdata = dataset[:]
```

This would cause the entire dataset to be read in and converted to `float32`, which is not what I want. I would like to have a reference to the dataset, but cast as a `float32` equivalent to `numpy.astype`. How do I create a reference to the `.astype('float32')` object so that I can pass it to another function for use?

An example:

```
import h5py as HDF
import numpy as np
intdata = (100*np.random.random(10)).astype('uint16')

# create the HDF dataset
def get_dataset_as_float():
    hf = HDF.File('data.h5', 'w')
    d = hf.create_dataset('data', data=intdata)
    print(d.dtype)
    # uint16

    with d.astype('float32'):
    # This won't work since the context expires. Returns a uint16 dataset reference
       return d

    # this works but causes the entire dataset to be read & converted
    # with d.astype('float32'):
    #   return d[:]
```

Furthermore, it seems like the astype context only applies when the data elements are accessed. This means that

```
def use_data():
   d = get_data_as_float()
   # this is a uint16 dataset

   # try to use it as a float32
   with d.astype('float32'):
       print(np.max(d))   # --> output is uint16
       print(np.max(d[:]))   # --> output is float32, but entire data is loaded
```

So is there not a numpy-esque way of using astype?

Comment: I don't think that `np.max(d)` is doing anything particularly clever here. Since `d` does not have its own `.max()` method, `np.max()` will read the array into memory and call `np.core.umath.maximum.reduce()` on it, using `d.dtype` to set the output type. The timings for `np.max(d)` and `np.max(d[:])` are near-identical.

Comment: @ali_m You may be right. I just chose np.max as way to look if an operation on the array returned the dtype. It's not important to my caluclations. I will mostly extract slices that I work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d.astype()` returns an `AstypeContext` object. If you look at the source for `AstypeContext` you'll get a better idea of what's going on:

```
class AstypeContext(object):

    def __init__(self, dset, dtype):
        self._dset = dset
        self._dtype = numpy.dtype(dtype)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._dset._local.astype = self._dtype

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._dset._local.astype = None
```

When you enter the `AstypeContext`, the `._local.astype` attribute of your dataset gets updated to the new desired type, and when you exit the context it gets changed back to its original value.

You can therefore get more or less the behaviour you're looking for like this:

```
def get_dataset_as_type(d, dtype='float32'):

    # creates a new Dataset instance that points to the same HDF5 identifier
    d_new = HDF.Dataset(d.id)

    # set the ._local.astype attribute to the desired output type
    d_new._local.astype = np.dtype(dtype)

    return d_new
```

When you now read from `d_new`, you will get `float32` numpy arrays back rather than `uint16`:

```
d = hf.create_dataset('data', data=intdata)
d_new = get_dataset_as_type(d, dtype='float32')

print(d[:])
# array([81, 65, 33, 22, 67, 57, 94, 63, 89, 68], dtype=uint16)
print(d_new[:])
# array([ 81.,  65.,  33.,  22.,  67.,  57.,  94.,  63.,  89.,  68.], dtype=float32)

print(d.dtype, d_new.dtype)
# uint16, uint16
```

Note that this doesn't update the `.dtype` attribute of `d_new` (which seems to be immutable). If you also wanted to change the `dtype` attribute, you'd probably need to subclass `h5py.Dataset` in order to do so.

Comment: Interesting. I did look into the AsTypeContext, but was not sure if setting the dtype myself would have some undesirable consequences. Will do some testing and come back to this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @arjmage I think it should be fine. `d._local` is a [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local) object, so your changes ought to be thread-safe. You can see [here](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/_hl/dataset.py#L394) that `d._local.dtype` is just used to set the `dtype` of the output numpy array that the data gets read out into. [`d.dtype` actually points to `d.id.dtype`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/_hl/dataset.py#L177), which is the identifier for the actual HDF5 object.

Answer (score 0):

The docs of `astype` seem to imply reading it all into a new location is its purpose. Thus your `return d[:]` is the most reasonable if you are to reuse the float-casting with many functions at seperate occasions.

If you know what you need the casting for and only need it once, you could switch things around and do something like:

```
def get_dataset_as_float(intdata, *funcs):
    with HDF.File('data.h5', 'w') as hf:
        d = hf.create_dataset('data', data=intdata)
        with d.astype('float32'):
            d2 = d[...]
            return tuple(f(d2) for f in funcs)
```

In any case, you want to make sure that `hf` is closed before leaving the function or else you will run into problems later on.

In general, I would suggest separating the casting and the loading/creating of the data-set entirely and passing the dataset as one of the function's parameters.

Above can be called as follows:

```
In [16]: get_dataset_as_float(intdata, np.min, np.max, np.mean)
Out[16]: (9.0, 87.0, 42.299999)
```